Facing issues in upgrading spring boot version for kie-server-spring-boot-starter
We are using kie-server-spring-boot-starter version 7.74.1.Final, currently we are using 2.5.9 version. We are upgrading spring boot version to  spring boot 3 to fix veracode vulnerabilities with spring lower versions.  After upgrading spring boot version to 3.2.2 kie server is not getting started.
below is the configuration related to kie server in application.yml file.
kieserver:
  serverId: app-service
  jbpmui:
    enabled: 'true'
  jbpm:
    enabled: 'true'
  swagger:
    enabled: 'true'
  drools:
    enabled: 'true'
  dmn:
    enabled: 'true'
  casemgmt:
    enabled: 'true'
  serverName: app-service

jbpm:
  executor:
    enabled: 'false'
     
org:
  kie:
    task:
      insecure: 'true'
    swagger:
      server:
        ext:
          disabled: 'false'
    server:
      bypass:
        auth:
          user: 'true'
      persistence:
        tm: org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.BitronixJtaPlatform
  jbpm:
    ht:
      custom:
        callback: com.server.adm.security.CustomUserGroupCallbackImpl
      callback: custom
cxf:
  path: /rest
narayana:
  dbcp:
    enabled: 'true'
    maxTotal: '20'



spring boot version we are using :  3.2.2
kie-server-spring-boot-starter  version :  7.74.1.Final
Java verson : 17

 

is kie server jars are compatible with spring boot 3? when we can expect latest version kie-server which is compatible with spring boot 3 and hibernate 6, if does not support currently?  It seems internal implementation of kie jars are compatible with hibernate 5 now where as spring boot 3 is compatible with hibernate 6.

If kie-server-spring-boot-starter is using SPring Boot 2.x you cannot upgrade to 3.x. Spring Boot 3.x moved to JakartaEE, while 2.x is still on JavaEE. The same will apply to all the classes in kie-server-spring-boot-starter.

Yes it seems. kie-server-spring-boot-starter using jbpm-persistence-jpa  which is compatible with hibernate 5. where as spring boot 3 compatible with hibernate 6 which is causing issue.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
